# How to integrate Admob with Cocos Creator 1.3.x

Tags: cocos2d-android, cocoscreator

I was wondering if anyone that have used cocos creator have ever managed to integrate admob banner in it.

I followed this [dcoumentation](http://docs.sdkbox.com/en/qa/integration-admob-to-creator/) I found online but my app first crashed and on 2nd attempt, ads appears white on screen and can't progress on app.

Sorry don't have any code to provide here but seeking anyone that has successfully integrated admob with it.